# Removing the +/- button from jqgrid grouping

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is there a way to remove the  tag that acts as a Show/Hide for groups in jqGrid?

It's the Span tag that has the +/- to show/hide the group contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following code in the `loadComplete` callback

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $("tr.jqgroup > td > span.ui-icon", this).hide();
}
```

`this` is DOM element of `<table>`. The rows (`<tr>`) of the grid having class `jqgroup` are responsible for the grouping header. The +/- symbol are in the child `<span>` element and it has class `ui-icon`.

Comment: Oleg, thank you, I was almost doing the same thing, just didn't put it in the actual "loadComplete" callback.  Thank you.